# MDX: What is Set Expression in Filter function?

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2013, ssas, sql-server-data-tools, business-intelligence

I'm using `AdventureWorksDW2008R2` and I'm trying to create a `calculated member` that will only consider rows in `[FactInternetSales]` where `[SalesAmount] > 300`.

In `Calculations` I tried something like below, but I'm getting error `MdxScript(Adventure Works DW2008R2) (8, 5) Too few arguments were passed to the FILTER function. The minimum argument count for the function is 2.`:

> filter(([Measures].[Sales Amount]>300))

I understand that I'm missing parameter `set expression`. Which would this parameter be in my example? I'm new to `SSAS` and `MDX`.

I'm creating this calculated member so that the totals I see in Excel only take into consideration rows in Fact table where [Sales Amount] > 300.

I'm also including the screenshot, maybe it helps:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> You have to use it like this

```
filter([FactInternetSales],([FactInternetSales].[SalesAmount]>300))
```

**filter** takes two args, first one is table name second one is the filter needs to be applied on that table

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but the Excel results still don't reflect this filter. This is what I see in Excel when I select the measure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vil9M.png